# Implementation of Incremental counter in R without using for loop

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 2 variables populated with approx.100K values.
I need to implement an `incremental counter` as the third column in the dataframe.
Below is data frame,

```
    **A**               **B**       
    1                     2          
    4                     3                   
    3                     2                   
    2                     0                   
    1                     0                   
    2                     0                   
    3                     2                   
    1                     2                   
    3                     2                     
    2                     0                   
    2                     0                   
    3                     0                   
    4                     0                      
    2                     0                   
    9                     1
```

Also, There are certain condition to be satisfied before implementing the counter as follows,
a. Counter should be incremented only when `A>=1` and `B=0`.
b. The **first 2 datapoints** where the condition `A>=1` and `B=0` satisfies should not increment the `counter`.

My expected output is as follows.

```
    **A**               **B**      **Incremental Counter  
    1                     2                 0    
    4                     3                 0  
    3                     2                 0  
    2                     0                 0  
    1                     0                 0  
    2                     0                 1  
    3                     2                 0  
    1                     2                 0  
    3                     2                 0    
    2                     0                 0  
    2                     0                 0  
    3                     0                 2  
    4                     0                 3     
    2                     0                 4  
    9                     1                 0
```

Thanks,

Comment: In that case, the first 1 in the counter column not satisfying the condition because A >1 is not true for the first 2 datapoints

Comment: @akrun I am sorry if my question is not clear enough. My issue is in my data frame row number `1`, `2`,`3`, doesnt satisfy the condition `A>=1 and B=0`, hence the counter column doesnt increment. But row number `4`, `5` and `6` do satisfies the condition `A>=1 & B=0`. But refering to my condition number 2 in my question, The first 2 data points should not be considered for counter incrementing so `Row 4 and 5` doesnt increment the counter, Hence counter is incremented from `Row number 6`

Comment: Row 5 does not satisfy that condition.

Comment: Under what conditions does the incremental counter reset to 0? Presumably an answer involves `cumsum(rle(A>1 & B==0))`.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll and @akrun I am very sorry for the unclear question. Correct condition is `A>=1 && B==0`. I have edited my post.

Comment: @Anmike I updated my post with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the condition is `A >=1 & B ==0` we can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- setDT(df1)[, grp := rleid(A >= 1 & B==0)][, .I[A >= 1 & B==0 & seq_len(.N)>2], grp]$V1
df1[i1, IncrementalCounter := seq_len(.N)][is.na(IncrementalCounter), 
            IncrementalCounter := 0][, grp := NULL][]   
#    A B IncrementalCounter
# 1: 1 2                  0
# 2: 4 3                  0
# 3: 3 2                  0
# 4: 2 0                  0
# 5: 1 0                  0
# 6: 2 0                  1
# 7: 3 2                  0
# 8: 1 2                  0
# 9: 3 2                  0
#10: 2 0                  0
#11: 2 0                  0
#12: 3 0                  2
#13: 4 0                  3
#14: 2 0                  4
#15: 9 1                  0
```

---

We can also do with `base R` using `rle`

```
rl <- with(df1, rle(A >=1 & B ==0))
r2 <- inverse.rle(within.list(rl, {i1 <- which(values)
             lengths[i1-1] <- lengths[i1-1] + 2
             lengths[i1] <- lengths[i1] - 2

         }))

cumsum(r2)*r2
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 2 3 4 0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 9L), B = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("A", "B"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using base R:

```
indices = df$A>=1 & df$B==0
reset.counter = indices!=c(NA,head(indices,-1))& indices==FALSE & c(NA,head(indices,-1))==TRUE
indices <- unname(split(indices, cumsum(seq_along(indices) %in% which(reset.counter))))
indices=unlist(lapply(indices, function(x) cumsum(x)>2 & x==TRUE  ))
indices[indices] = seq(1,sum(indices))
df$C = indices
```

Output:

```
   A B C
1  1 2 0
2  4 3 0
3  3 2 0
4  2 0 0
5  1 0 0
6  2 0 1
7  3 2 0
8  1 2 0
9  3 2 0
10 2 0 0
11 2 0 0
12 3 0 2
13 4 0 3
14 2 0 4
15 9 1 0
```

Comment: Modified my code, not as fancy as your base R code, but it does the trick ;)